# SQLalchemy filter cast datetime by day of week

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-datetime

I have a Datetime column and I am trying to filter that column by everything occurring on a Saturday.

I can filter Datetime by casting it to a date and comparing it to a date string like this:

```
session.query(SQL_table).filter(cast(SQL_table.datetime_column, Date) == '2020-7-1').all()
```

But how do I say I want that column to return everything that is on a certain day of the week? I tried this:

```
session.query(SQL_table).filter(cast(SQL_table.datetime_column, Date).strftime('%A') == 'Saturday').all()
```

This gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'Cast' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'strftime'
```

So how do I cast the column to a weekday and filter it by a specific day then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you can specify function which users use to extract day of week in your SQL dialect using function generator from sqlalchemy package. For example, Transact-SQL has *format()* function, Oracle SQL has *to_char(date_column, 'D')* function for day's of week extraction. Using this approach you can specify custom function that will be suitable for your SQL dialect.

```
from sqlalchemy import func

day_of_week_num = 6
day_of_week_str = 'Sunday'

# Example for Transact-SQL
session.query(SQL_table).filter(func.format(SQL_table.datetime_column, 'dddd') == day_of_week_str).all()

# Example for Oracle SQL
session.query(SQL_table).filter(func.to_char(SQL_table.datetime_column, 'D') == day_of_week_num).all()
```

Comment: Hmm thanks. I am using SQL Server btw, so I used the first solution. That makes sense, but I get this error:

ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart. (1023) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')

Comment: I changed datepart() to format() function because datepart's first argument is internal dw object which is not available to get inside sqlalchemy. Can you try new approach for Transact SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `func.dayofweek`

```
from sqlalchemy import func

...

# 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ..., 7 = Saturday.
# Therefore, to get Saturday:

session.query(SQL_table).filter(func.dayofweek(
                    SQL_table.datetime_column) == 7).all()
```